# EditText inside a ListView on a onCreateView

Tags: android, listview

I have a List view with two EditText in and want to modify the problem is that I'm working it from a fregment and I only onCreateView to work
could help me?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calcu, container, false);
    c = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    lista = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);

            cantidad = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cantidad);
            precio = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.precio);
            id = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.id);
            // how to get the position of the selected EditText to access him
            position( X ) cantidad.getText().toString(); 
            position( X ) precio.getText().toString();

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Define modify, what exactly do you want to do with those 2 EditTexts?

Comment: I want to enter a number in the EditText and to save in a  list of a database

Comment: You could pretty much do anything inside a Fragment just like in an Activity. So, I dont understand which part are you stuck.

Comment: if I declare only EditText with textWhacher the application stops and throws an error and if I do whit setOnFocusChangeListener not recognize the position and just change the first

Comment: Why do you want to know the position of the EditTexts? I think there is a getX() or getY() method. Im not sure.

Comment: For attaching listeners to a view within a list item, you will need to create a custom adapter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view

Comment: position are not important but they can be used to save the info